# Convert numeric month to string month name in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x

I would like to convert the numeric representation of a month to its name. I would like to do this in a Jinja template, using Ansible.

E.g.:

- when given `1` the output should be `Jan`
- when given `2` the output should be `Feb`
- etc.

Here is my template tentative at achieving this:

```yaml
m_usg_month: "{{data.month | to_datetime('%b')}}"
```

But, this gives me the error:

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "ValueError: time data '1' does not match format '%b'"}

***Input***

```
data:
  month: "1"
```

***Expected Output***

```
m_usg_month: "Jan"
```

Comment: [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) doesn't provide this functionality. [calendar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html) does but is not implemented in Ansible. You will have to write a simple dictionary or a function on your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is coming from the fact that you are providing your desired *output format* to the filter `to_datetime`, while what you actually need to do is to pass the ***input format***.

Then, use the [`strftime` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) on the resulting `datetime`, with your desired output format, this time.

So:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ (data.month | string | to_datetime('%m')).strftime('%b') }}"
```

---

As a full-fledged example:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ (data.month | string | to_datetime('%m')).strftime('%b') }}"
  loop: "{{ range(1, 13) }}"
  vars:
    data:
      month: "{{ item }}"
```

Would yield:

```
TASK [debug] *************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=1) => 
  msg: Jan
ok: [localhost] => (item=2) => 
  msg: Feb
ok: [localhost] => (item=3) => 
  msg: Mar
ok: [localhost] => (item=4) => 
  msg: Apr
ok: [localhost] => (item=5) => 
  msg: May
ok: [localhost] => (item=6) => 
  msg: Jun
ok: [localhost] => (item=7) => 
  msg: Jul
ok: [localhost] => (item=8) => 
  msg: Aug
ok: [localhost] => (item=9) => 
  msg: Sep
ok: [localhost] => (item=10) => 
  msg: Oct
ok: [localhost] => (item=11) => 
  msg: Nov
ok: [localhost] => (item=12) => 
  msg: Dec
```

Answer (score 2):

Create filter. For example,

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
├── pb.yml
└── plugins
    └── filter
        ├── calendar.py
```

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
gathering = explicit
inventory = $PWD/hosts
filter_plugins = $PWD/plugins/filter
stdout_callback = yaml
```

```bash
shell> cat hosts
localhost
```

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for i in range(1,13) %}
          {{ i }} {{ i|calendar_month_abbr }} {{ i|calendar_month_name }}
          {% endfor %}
```

```py
shell> cat plugins/filter/calendar.py 
import calendar


def calendar_month_name(num):
    return calendar.month_name[num]


def calendar_month_abbr(num):
    return calendar.month_abbr[num]


class FilterModule(object):

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'calendar_month_name': calendar_month_name,
            'calendar_month_abbr': calendar_month_abbr,
        }
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    1 Jan January
    2 Feb February
    3 Mar March
    4 Apr April
    5 May May
    6 Jun June
    7 Jul July
    8 Aug August
    9 Sep September
    10 Oct October
    11 Nov November
    12 Dec December
```